# REACT Website npm start doesn't start website

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I use NPM Start it opens up a webpage in Chrome but after a while, it says

> "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage."

[GitHub Repository for the code. I can't give a small piece fo code because I don't know what is giving the error.](https://github.com/kevinpleong/PDT-React)

I would like it to run and show my webpages. Not sure why it isn't working. The first time I started the server using NPM start it gave me this page. [image: Page loading error]

Comment: Can you share the logs in browser's developer console? If you're not seeing logs, try to enable "preserve logs" and refresh the page

Comment: What does it say on your console?

Comment: There is issue with line `import Logo from './Assets/Pawsitively Delicious Logo.jpg';` in `components` -->`Home.js`. You are trying to import image with spaces, and why have you created test.html?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the Navbar.js

The issue is your class name here was `Nav` but Nav was also used in the render function. I have renamed Nav to CustomNavbar and imported the bootstrap nav from the npm package.

change your code to this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar  from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import { Button, FormControl, Form, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

export default class CustomNavbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Pawsitively Delicious</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="AboutUs.js">About Us</Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown title="Ingredients" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="./TypesOfDogTreats">Types of Dog Treats</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="AllIngredients.js">Ingredients</NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <Form inline>
              <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
              <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
            </Form>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  } // END OF RENDER
} // END OF Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, for me the problem was caused by adding a button component so i deleted a part of my codes

```
const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle)?buttonStyle:STYLES[0]
const checkButtonSize = SIZE.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize: SIZE[0]
```

[try this link for more options on how to solve it](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

[1](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):